# android studio , auto refresh data json url every 60 second

Tags: android, json, android-studio

am new in android studio and I am trying to make my simple app get JSON data from URL using Volley , everything good but i want to do auto refresh data json .am try to do but not working .

my code if any one can help my

```
package imo.meteoiraq;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.security.Timestamp;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RequestQueue rq;
TextView timeDesc,tempDesc,windspeedDesc,windguestDesc,humdityDesc;
    int ages;
    int temp;
    int windspeed;
    int windguest;
    int humdity;
    long timeupdate;

    String url="/stationlookup?station=I1410&units=metric&v=2.0&format=json";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rq= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        timeDesc= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeupdateDesc);
        tempDesc= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempid);
        windspeedDesc= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.windid);
        windguestDesc= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.windgustid);
        humdityDesc= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humdid);

        sendjsonrequest();
    }
public void  sendjsonrequest(){
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {

                JSONObject stationsJO = response.getJSONObject("stations");
                JSONObject I1410JO = stationsJO.getJSONObject("I1410");
                 temp = I1410JO.getInt("temperature");
                 windspeed = I1410JO.getInt("wind_speed");
                 windguest = I1410JO.getInt("wind_gust_speed");
                 humdity = I1410JO.getInt("humidity");
                timeupdate = I1410JO.getLong("updated")* 1000L;

                 tempDesc.setText(Integer.toString(temp));
                 windspeedDesc.setText(Integer.toString(windspeed));
                 windguestDesc.setText(Integer.toString(windguest));
                 humdityDesc.setText(Integer.toString(humdity));
                 timeDesc.setText(getDate(timeupdate));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    rq.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

    private String getDate(long  timeStamp){
        try{
            DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
            return sdf.format(netDate);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            return "xx";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to hit volley request every 60 secs??

Comment: yes i mean auto update, without from app and back agin

Comment: what do you mean by without from app and back again?? Can you explain clearly

Comment: @sumit , i mean when i enter to app i want see auto update data every 60 sec .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to do that. For e.g 
`

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             // polling code 
             handler.postDelayed(this, SIXTY_SECONDS);
         }
    };Handler.postDelayed(runnable, DELAY_TIME) ;`
```

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'handler'

Comment: Edited, you need to create an instance of Handler

Comment: unknown ' class ' runnable

Comment: handler.postDelayed(runnable, DELAY_TIME); with small letter, otherwise it will consider it as static class

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sendjsonrequest();
                handler.postDelayed(this,6000);//60 second delay
            }
        };handler.postDelayed(runnable,Initial_Delay_time);
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: thank you , cannot resolve symbol 'postDelayed'

Comment: make sure you're importing import android.os.Handler; android os handler

Comment: the code working fine but there no update !! ?

Comment: so check whether you're getting some new data on the server or not??

Comment: yes there update every 60 sec , when i change value sec i see some delay to show data

Comment: can we use postAtTime ?

Comment: I didn't get your point is the update coming or not??

Comment: no, the data its same in app but in server is different data

Comment: share your php code??

Comment: data json not php

Comment: you must have something on server side which sends you response when you hit the url??

Comment: am get information form my weather station via data json my station updata every 60 sec , when i enter to app i see new data but when i keep in side app over 60 sec there no auto update .

Comment: can we make pull up for refresh ?

Comment: yes you can also do that

Comment: any idea for code :) ?

Comment: wait i'll share the code for that but I am trying to figure out why you're not getting update second time when you hit the request

Comment: i dont know , if i put handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000); there delay to show data if i make him 6000 the data show immediately

Comment: wait i see some thing

Comment: can you share the updated code how have you used the handler??

Comment: he just update too times then stop update , do you thing about asynctask ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149074/discussion-between-sumit-and-aligassan).